# iTunes Mp3 Add Returning Nil Via Scripting Bridge In ObjC and Swift And Doesn't Import

Tags: objective-c, swift, itunes, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to import a downloaded MP3 into iTunes. My app is for OSX using Swift, and I've tried doing this both in Swift code and in ObjC using interoperability. I've generated the iTunes.h using sdef and sdp. I'm importing it in my Bridging Header for the Swift attempt and in my .m file for the ObjC attempt. I've added Scripting Bridge to my build.

This is my first program in Swift or ObjC (my experience is in C#) so this may be something simple I don't have the experience to realize.

Here is my ObjC code:

```
NSString *filepath = "~/Music/test.mp3";
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesPlaylist *pl;
for (iTunesSource *source in sources) {
    if([source kind] == iTunesESrcLibrary) {
        SBElementArray *libraries = [source libraryPlaylists];
        pl = [libraries objectAtIndex:1];
        break;
    }
}
iTunesTrack *track = [iTunes add:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]] to: pl];
```

Everything compiles and runs, but the iTunes add returns nil (and more importantly, doesn't add to iTunes). I've tried using different Playlists from the Library, and difference Sources as well. I've tried using a different MP3 file. And as I said, I've written it in Swift as well. All give me the same result.

Comment: Where exactly do you want the song to end up in iTunes? Just added to the library, or in a specific playlist, etc?

Comment: In the library for now, though I will need the option to create a playlist and add it to that at some point in the future.

Comment: I checked `[iTunes lastError]` and I'm getting this:
The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -1708.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I was fetching the path for MyMusic incorrectly. You can't just use the tilde, you have to resolve it:

```
NSString *musicDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [musicDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mp3"];
```

Or with Swift:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.MusicDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let musicDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as? NSURL
let filepath = musicDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.mp3")
```

At this point, I no longer needed to mess with any of the source searching either, I could just pass nil as the playlist:

```
iTunesTrack *track = [iTunes add:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath], nil] to: nil];
```

I still need an Objective C wrapper around the actual add method, however, which is connected to the Swift programming via the Bridging Header. If I try to use the add method in Swift directly, I get linker errors which seem unrelated to the original issue, so I won't address.